# Плагин для jQuery. Подробная информация при наведении.

Tags: jquery

Где можно найти готовый плагин, как на сайте:

```
http://www.ovas.ru/
```

Comment: та самому можно написать минут за 20. не ленитесь)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/4R8kX/